# Assign UIButton target from variable

Tags: swift, uibutton, swift3

Is it possible to assign a target from a variable? I have a function which adds and removes a target which is quite redundant and I would like to truncate it a bit. I've created a `typealias` which replicates the parameters expected for a `UIButtonTarget` but unable to assign a target without the parameters. Error: 
**Missing argument for parameter 'action' in call**

```
 @IBAction func didTapActionBtn(sender: UIButton){
    typealias btnTarget = (_: AnyObject?, action: Selector, for: UIControlEvents)
    let prevTarget: btnTarget = (self, action: #selector(self.showPrevApp), for: .touchUpInside)

    if sender.tag == 0{
      sender.tag = 1
      prevBtn.removeTarget(prevTarget) //*Missing argument for parameter 'action' in call
      nextBtn.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showNextApp), for: .touchUpInside)
    }else{
      sender.tag = 0
      prevBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showPrevApp), for: .touchUpInside)
      nextBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showNextApp), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do (*Implicit Tuple Splat Behavior*) used to work in Swift, but it was deprecated in Swift 2.2 and removed in Swift 3.

Here is the Swift 2.2 error message:

> Passing 3 arguments to a callee as a single tuple value is deprecated

See the following for the motivation for removing the tuple splat behavior:

[SE-0029 Remove Implicit Tuple Splat Behavior](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0029-remove-implicit-tuple-splat.md)